# is there master date time pattern which will work for every similar date time patterns

Tags: java, datetime-format, localdatetime

My consumer received time format is `String` with value `20/5/14_9:22:25` or `20/5/14_9:22:5` or `20/5/14_12:22:25` or `20/10/14_9:2:25` etc...

all the above have very diffrent date time pattern from `yy/MM/dd_HH:mm:ss`
and there can be many posiblity's of having single digit day,month,hour,minute and/or seconds.

is there a masterpattern which will i can use for `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format)` which will work for all the above pattern??

Comment: all are looking same excpet some value changes

Comment: What have you tried? The pattern looks the same to me

Comment: @ScaryWombat the patterns are `yy/MM/dd_hh:mm:ss` most of the above example differ from it

Comment: @komatiraju032 it's the pattern im more focused here not the values

Comment: you can use regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The patterns look the same

```
      DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yy/M/dd_H:mm:s");
      LocalDate parsedDate = LocalDate.parse("20/5/14_9:22:25", formatter);
      System.out.println(parsedDate);
      parsedDate = LocalDate.parse("20/5/14_9:22:5", formatter);
      System.out.println(parsedDate);
      parsedDate = LocalDate.parse("20/10/14_9:22:25", formatter);
      System.out.println(parsedDate);
```

**output**

```
2020-05-14
2020-05-14
2020-10-14
```

Counter-intuitively but very practically, for numbers one pattern letter, for example `M` or `H`, does not mean one digit but rather “as many digits as it takes”. So `M` parses both `5` and `10` (and even `05`). `H` parses `9` and `12`, etc. By contrast two pattern letters, for example `MM` or `HH`, means exactly two digits, so will not work for parsing neither a month of 5 nor an hour of 9. It would require `05` or `09`. Or as the documentation puts it:

> **Number:** If the count of letters is one, then the value is output using the minimum number of digits and without padding. Otherwise, the
>   count of digits is used as the width of the output field, with the
>   value zero-padded as necessary. …

So if you need to accept one-digit day of month or one-digit minute of the hour, also use one pattern letter `d` and `m`, respectively.

But having a hour of `29` (as you had in earlier versions of the question) is wrong.

**Documentation link:** [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: they look similar but are not the same

Comment: Did you try the **one** pattern that I provided `"yy/M/dd_H:mm:s"` ?

Comment: no quite but similar `yy/M/d_H:m:s` , it worked, so if you edit your answewr with this patter i will accept , as your pattern did lead me to the answer

Answer (score 1):

The answer by [Scary Wombat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310289/scary-wombat) is to the point. I'm adding this answer to just let you know that apart from `LocalDate`, the package, `java.time` also has a `LocalDateTime` which you can use to deal with date and time both as shown below:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yy/M/dd_H:mm:s");
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("20/5/14_9:22:25", formatter);
        System.out.println(ldt);
        ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("20/5/14_9:22:5", formatter);
        System.out.println(ldt);
        ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("20/10/14_9:22:25", formatter);
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-05-14T09:22:25
2020-05-14T09:22:05
2020-10-14T09:22:25
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning `LocalDateTime` . The OP originally posted (as a comment) his code where he was using just `LocalDate` - Strange I know.

Comment: Thanks, @ScaryWombat for always encouraging me. More than anything, I always get inspired by your great spirit.