# Get the Month from a date string

Tags: java, string, date, date-format, dateformatter

I have a String input of date "10/10/2020" (assume they are always going to be separated with /) and I am trying to store each category in a private int variable already defined as Month, Day, and year.

I used the parseInt, indexOf, and substring methods to find the month and store it in the month variable but I am having a hard time figuring out how I can have the program read the day. We are to assume that the month and day can be in "00" or "0" formats.

This is how I am reading the month from the string and this is what I got so far for reading the day but I am getting an error.

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 2, end 0, length 8

This is my code so far please let me know what mistake I am doing.

```
    int firstSlash = date.indexOf("/");
    int secondSlash = date.indexOf("/", firstSlash);
    
    month = Integer.parseInt (date.substring (0, firstSlash));
    day = Integer.parseInt (date.substring(firstSlash+1, secondSlash-1));
```

I don't want the answer but please help me understand the logic of where I am going wrong because based on my understanding I seem to be getting the Index values between the first and second slash and converting the String value into an int.

Comment: You shouldn't parse manually. There are libraries for that e.g. Calendar

Comment: But assuming you do want to parse yourself, use split ("/")

Comment: Its for a class assignment, thats why we are being told to do it manually. I need some help understanding the logic.

Comment: In the "real world" - USE A STANDARD JAVA DATE LIBRARY! If your (admittedly artificial) homework assignment won't let you do that, consider using a [regex](https://www.baeldung.com/java-date-regular-expressions). Failing all else, your "firstSlash" code looks OK. You need to add some "diagnostic temp variables" and/or step through the debugger to troubleshoot your remaining code. `begin 2, end 0` should give you a hint as to the problem :)  FYI, "split()" should also work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First you need to search from next index of first `/` found means you should use `firstSlash + 1` instead `firstSlash` in `date.indexOf("/", firstSlash)`.
- `.substring()`'s 2nd paramerter is exclusive, so you need to use `secondSlash` instead of `secondSlash-1` in `date.substring(firstSlash+1, secondSlash-1)`.

Your code should be like

```
String date = "10/10/2020";
int firstSlash = date.indexOf("/");
int secondSlash = date.indexOf("/", firstSlash + 1);

int month = Integer.parseInt (date.substring (0, firstSlash));
int day = Integer.parseInt (date.substring(firstSlash+1, secondSlash));
```

It's better to use `LocalDate` to store date and use `DateTimeFormatter` to parse the date.

Comment: Awesome that worked but could you elaborate where I was going wrong? Why did we do firstSlash + 1 in the indexof method?

Comment: I already added in the answer, you need to search from next index of first `/` found means `firstSlash + 1`. You are currently search from the index first `/` found  so it will return that index again.

Comment: Wouldn't be easiest to split the date like `date.split("/")`?

Comment: @FSm OP asks to understand what's wrong with this code actually. I know you mean something like `String[] splited = date.split("/");int month = Integer.parseInt (splited[0]);int day = Integer.parseInt (splited[1]);`

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want the answer but please help me understand the logic of
> where I am going wrong because …

That's the attitude I and we like, the attitude of a true learner. I will provide useful information and links, not solve your error for you.

1. Like others I recommend that you use java.time, the modern java date and time API, for your date work.
2. You sem to have some indexing inaccuracies in your code.

### java.time

Use the `LocalDate` class of java.time for a date and its `getMonth` or `getMonthValue` method for getting the month. java.time can parse a date string where month and day can be in "00" or "0" formats. If you try it and run into doubts, a new question from you is always welcome.

### What went wrong in your code

This should suffice for identifying the flaws in your code:

1. To start with what I think you already know well: indices in Java are 0-based.
2. The two-argument `String.indexOf(String, int)` searches the string from the given index *inclusive*. If the substring searched for is at the index you specify, the same index is returned.
3. The two-argument `substring(int, int)` gives you the substring from the from-index *inclusive* to the to-index *exclusive*. The to-index needs to be at least as great as the from-index, or a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` will be thrown. The exception message mentions the two indices that you passed to `substring()`, which may give you a chance to think backward to where they came from.

### Reservation

I know I'm late at the party. I still couldn't resist posting what I think is a good answer.

### Links

- For java.time

  - [Oracle tutorial: date time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/)
  - [Documentation of `LocalDate.getMonth()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#getMonth())
  - [Documentation of `DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)
  - A related question on parsing dates with numbers that may be one or two digits: [is there master date time pattern which will work for every similar date time patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61791762/is-there-master-date-time-pattern-which-will-work-for-every-similar-date-time-pa)
- For string indexing

  - [Documentation of `String.indexOf(String, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,int))
  - [Documentation of `String.substring(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int))

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way of doing it is by using the date-time API e.g. [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) as shown below:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDate = "10/10/2020";
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(strDate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/u"));
        int year = date.getYear();
        int month = date.getMonthValue();
        int dayOfMonth = date.getDayOfMonth();

        System.out.println("Year: " + year + ", Month: " + month + ", Day of month: " + dayOfMonth);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Year: 2020, Month: 10, Day of month: 10
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.